# Any idea if ExpandableListView is going to be deprecated in the near future ?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, expandablelistview, expandablerecyclerview

I hope my question doesn't violate the rules of StackOverFlow. I am writing an android app and want to implement a list view that is expandable. I am aware of expandableLisView and 3rd party libraries of different versions of expandable recycler view such as [this](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view) or [this](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview) . Although, I am trying to avoid using libraries and be as native as possible. knowing that recyclerView is more recent and potentially more efficient than listViews, I am afraid that expandableListView gets deprecated at some point in the near future and google comes up with something like that for recycler view.

Just wondering if anyone is aware of such a thing or if expandableListView would be a safe bet to go with. Thanks a lot for your input.

Comment: "I hope my question doesn't violate the rules of StackOverFlow" -- well, the only people who could answer your question definitively are employees of Google, and they do not comment publicly on future changes like this. Anyone else can only offer opinions. Also note that "deprecated" means "there is something else that we suggest that you use". Deprecated classes usually still work, giving you time to migrate to some alternative implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I thought there is no harm in asking, perhaps someone knows something that I don't know.

Comment: You'll note that there's a complete lack of expandable lists in the [material design guidelines](https://material.google.com/)